# Extracting and formatting results of cor.test on multiple pairs of columns

Tags: r, statistics, correlation

I am trying to generate a table output of a correlation matrix. Specifically, I am using a for loop in order to identify a correlation between all data in columns 4:40 to column 1. While the results of the table are decent, it does **not** identify what is being compared to what. In checking attributes of `cor.test`,I find that data.name is being given as `x[1]` and `y[1]` which is not good enough to trace back which columns is being compared to what. Here is my code:

```
input <- read.delim(file="InputData.txt", header=TRUE)
x<-input[,41, drop=FALSE]
y=input[,4:40]
corr.values <- vector("list", 37)
for (i in 1:length(y) ){
  corr.values[[i]] <- cor.test(x[[1]], y[[i]], method="pearson")
}
lres <- sapply(corr.values, `[`, c("statistic","p.value","estimate","method", "data.name"))
lres<-t(lres)
write.table(lres, file="output.xls", sep="\t",row.names=TRUE)
```

The output file looks like this:

```
       statistic        p.value     estimate                                  method            data.name   
1   -2.030111981    0.042938137 -0.095687495    Pearson's product-moment correlation    x[[1]] and y[[i]]
2   -2.795786248    0.005400938 -0.131239287    Pearson's product-moment correlation    x[[1]] and y[[i]]
3   -2.099114632    0.036368337 -0.098908573    Pearson's product-moment correlation    x[[1]] and y[[i]]
4   -1.920649487    0.055413178 -0.090571599    Pearson's product-moment correlation    x[[1]] and y[[i]]
5   -1.981326962    0.048168291 -0.093408365    Pearson's product-moment correlation    x[[1]] and y[[i]]
6   -2.80390736      0.00526909 -0.131613912    Pearson's product-moment correlation    x[[1]] and y[[i]]
7   -1.265138839    0.206482153 -0.059798855    Pearson's product-moment correlation    x[[1]] and y[[i]]
8   -2.861448156    0.004415411 -0.134266636    Pearson's product-moment correlation    x[[1]] and y[[i]]
9   -2.103403363    0.035990039 -0.099108672    Pearson's product-moment correlation    x[[1]] and y[[i]]
10  -3.610094985    0.000340807 -0.168498786    Pearson's product-moment correlation    x[[1]] and y[[i]]
```

Clearly, this is not perfect as rows are numbered and can't tell which correlation is to what. Is there a way to fix this? I tried many solutions but none worked.I know that the trick must be in editing the `data.name` attribute however I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a way to return a data frame with all the `cor.test` results that also includes the names of the variables for which each correlation was calculated: We create a function to extract the relevant results of `cor.test` then use `mapply` to apply the function to each pair of variables for which we want the correlations. `mapply` returns a list, so we use `do.call(rbind, ...)` to turn it into a data frame.

```
# Function to extract correlation coefficient and p-values
corrFunc <- function(var1, var2, data) {
  result = cor.test(data[,var1], data[,var2])
  data.frame(var1, var2, result[c("estimate","p.value","statistic","method")], 
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}

## Pairs of variables for which we want correlations
vars = data.frame(v1=names(mtcars)[1], v2=names(mtcars)[-1])

# Apply corrFunc to all rows of vars
corrs = do.call(rbind, mapply(corrFunc, vars[,1], vars[,2], MoreArgs=list(data=mtcars), 
                              SIMPLIFY=FALSE))

     var1 var2   estimate      p.value statistic                               method
cor   mpg  cyl -0.8475514 9.380327e-10 -8.747152 Pearson's product-moment correlation
cor1  mpg disp -0.7761684 1.787835e-07 -6.742389 Pearson's product-moment correlation
cor2  mpg   hp  0.4186840 1.708199e-02  2.525213 Pearson's product-moment correlation
cor3  mpg drat  0.6811719 1.776240e-05  5.096042 Pearson's product-moment correlation
cor4  mpg   wt  0.4802848 5.400948e-03  2.999191 Pearson's product-moment correlation
cor5  mpg qsec  0.6640389 3.415937e-05  4.864385 Pearson's product-moment correlation
cor6  mpg   vs  0.5998324 2.850207e-04  4.106127 Pearson's product-moment correlation
cor7  mpg   am  1.0000000 0.000000e+00       Inf Pearson's product-moment correlation
cor8  mpg gear -0.8676594 1.293959e-10 -9.559044 Pearson's product-moment correlation
cor9  mpg carb -0.8521620 6.112687e-10 -8.919699 Pearson's product-moment correlation
```

Comment: Thank you. If i want to output the 'r' along with its direction (+ or -), which attribute should i add to data.frame(var1, var2, result[c("estimate","p.value","statistic","method")], 
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Comment: one thing that confused me and reading about it didn't help was 'stringsAsFactors=FALSE". What does this do exactly? And why did you choose it?

Comment: If you set `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` character class columns will remain character. Otherwise, R will set them to factor class.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your first comment. The "estimate" column *is* the r value (where "r value" is the correlation coefficient).

Comment: i got confused because the output was shifted to the left. thanks a lot for your responses.