# variable-assignment: Difference between "<-" and "=" in a certain post & avoiding using "return"

Tags: r, return, variable-assignment

I have found the following solution on here about the post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34327262/2994949

The user *eipi10* uses `=` insted of `<-` to assign a value to the `corrFunc` function. Why does he do this?

Also, he/she creates the data.frame in the next line, but does not use a `return` to have that data.frame returned from the code. The function works, so I wonder why and how.

**EDIT**
Does it provide any advantages to used or not to use the `return`command? This is something that has not been answered before, that's why I think this is not a duplicate.

*I tried to ask this in a comment, but I need 50 reputation to put comments and why I put an answer in the initial thread, it was immediately deleted. Could anybody tell me, how to ask about a solution I find in a thread when I can not comment and can not post an answer?*

Thank you.

**EDIT**

The first part of my question has been answered partly by the link but I still do not understand why the `return` is avoided. thanks :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/assignment-operators-in-r-and

Comment: For the part on `return()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738823/explicitly-calling-return-in-a-function-or-not/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?return`:

> If the end of a function is reached without calling return, the value of the last evaluated expression is returned.

For example,

```
f <- function() {
   x <- 1
   x
}
```

is equivalent to the same function with `return(x)` as the last statement. Perhaps surprisingly,

```
f <- function() {
   x <- 1
}
```

also returns the same value, but returns it *invisibly*. There is a minor schism (perhaps not quite as strong as the `=` vs. `<-` schism) about whether it's better practice to always use an explicit `return()`: I believe it is good practice (because it makes the intention of the code more explicit), but many old-school R programmers prefer the implicit return value.

Comment: Does it provide any advantages using an explicit return? Just wondering.

Comment: only stylistic/readability as far as I know

Comment: Ok, so since I am newby and I am trying to develop a good style, is it recommend to use it or is it considered redundant code which should be left out?

Comment: It depends who you ask!  I would recommend it but other experienced R users would consider it redundant.

Comment: ok I will use it then, it helps me. Thanks and have a good day.

Comment: Google's R style guide doesn't mention whether to use `return` or not, but its example function does https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml#examplefunction - some other style guides out there recommend using `return`, and I can't find any that say "dont".

Comment: @Spacedman The [tidyverse styleguide](https://style.tidyverse.org/functions.html#return) says not to use it. Regardless of style guide, a lot of the core R package code (but not all of it) omits it. And, finally, given that R is a functional programming language where *every function call has a value*, using `return` is inconsistent with the mental model of R execution logic.